# Fail-safe reliable mule file endpoints

Tags: mule

I was trying to build a reliable mechanism for mule file endpoints . The idea was to log every message in the database along with the processing status. In case the server goes down i could read the database and get the status of the message , if the message was not successfully processed wanted to retry. Can you give me some pointers for building such a framework.Can processors (db readers) be executed at the time of mule startup to get the information from db.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need the following things to be taken care of

1) Take the message out of the flow and store in database

-- For this you need to use some pattern or more precisely to say a separate process that stores it in the database

SOLUTION  --

a)You can use wire tap pattern to spawn a separate process to store the every message you get into the database . This wire tap is another flow that you can design.

b)You can use a Flow reference where you can make it as a async so a separate flow is started with the message you need to store in the database.

Problem you need to look into is when you restart the flow the same message is logged in to the data base and if it is not desired by you then add more tweaks to the same solution given above.

2) If any error happens (in your case it is server down)then you need to restart the flow

-- For this you need to set you flow in such a way that you can call back your flow from where you have stopped or error happens .

SOLUTION --

a)Use an endpoint mostly vm endpoint and call the flow when you need to restart.Use a java program that sends a message to the vm endpoint which is stated above